# Template suggestions with page argument is not working - Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have created a page with name news, Page id is **25**

Now I created a page in template with name **page--node--25.tpl.php** which is also working fine

I have created a view as a **block** with **Contextual filters**.  and assign that block to **news page**

I am passing argument as

news/1 . here 1 is for contextual filter.

Now when I am accessing example.com/news/1.

It is showing page not found.

Any idea?

Comment: You can only access a page that has actual content. If there is no node with id=1, there is no content to show. All associated blocks won't be shown either

Comment: did you set the url for the node (overwrite) it to be 'news', if not it might still think it's only node/25